# send a parameter that execute a cmd line with

Tags: html, cmd

hi all i have a form with one parameter "Draft" , and i want to send draft with send button to execute a function in the command line.

```
   C:\PDF>pdfprint.exe -printer "docPrint" -firstpage 1 -lastpage 1 -wtext "Draft"
    -wo 100 -wa 50 -wf "Arial" C:\readme.pdf
```

the html form code

```
<FORM 
   ACTION="..........." 
   onReset="return confirm('Do you really want to reset the form?')"  >
     <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="query">
     <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT> 
     <INPUT TYPE=RESET VALUE="Start All Over">
</FORM>
```

what should i insert in the action ?

Comment: i'm asking ? u know :\ , maybe with js?

Comment: what do u mean HTML for browsers? it should be run on IE or chrome

Comment: Ok. That is what I'm asking about. Just to be sure that it is not something special.

Comment: you cannot control computer using JavaScript

Comment: no it is not just try to print a page with whater mark that i send

Comment: ok i understand way i cant do this thank anyway

Answer (score 0):

Once that HTML is a part of regular web page, than you can't do that with only HTML/JS. You will also need some server side language which will accept browser's request, read posted form and do something based on received values (in your case - run printer from cmd line). Take a look at PHP, asp.net or anything else you like (besides, it will be printed on server, not on client machine. JS does not allow you to control what is happening on client PC outside your page). User may decide to print your page, and in that case you can add special style sheet link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/css/print_message.css" />
```

For instance, in my project I have this line when I do not want content on some page to be available for printing (print_message.css will hide all content and show a message about printing is restricted).